# Ayuda para realizar un redireccionamiento 301

Tags: html, .htaccess

tengo un problema con un redireccionamiento 301 en mi pagina web, actualmente estoy intentando redireccionar http://www.emprendimientoysalud.com/productos-seytu hacia -----> http://www.emprendimientoysalud.com/productos-seytu.html y http://www.emprendimientoysalud.com/productos-omnilife hacia -----> http://www.emprendimientoysalud.com/productos-omnilife.html .Como pueden ver quiero redireccionar de folder hacia url. Dentro de las carpetas productos-seytu y productos-omnilife, tengo más archivos .html. El problema surge que, cuando hago una redireccion 301 como las siguientes:

```
Redirect 301 /productos-omnilife/ http://www.emprendimientoysalud.com/productos-omnilife.html
Redirect 301 /productos-seytu/ http://www.emprendimientoysalud.com/productos-seytu.html
```

Los enlaces que tengo en los archivos: productos-omnilife.html y productos-seytu.html se muestran como inválidos a ir a ellos. Ejemplo: ---> http://www.emprendimientoysalud.com/productos-seytu.htmldelineador-mate.html <--- Se muestra este enlace con la redireccion 301. El enlace no se muestra tal y como lo pongo en el archivo .html, es decir: http://www.emprendimientoysalud.com/productos-seytu/delineador-mate.html
¿ Cómo hago para evitar esos errores de url en los enlaces con una Redireccion 301 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que quieres redireccionar a una url que no existe?

```
Redirect 301 /productos-omnilife/ http://www.emprendimientoysalud.com/productos-omnilife.html
```

el archivo productos-omnilife.html no exite en la carpeta "/productos-omnilife/".

Lo recomendable para que no cargue las carpetas como tal es nombrando el archivo principal de la carpeta a index.html, me dirás que para fines de SEO quieres que tenga el nombre de la sección, pero si ya tienes el nombre en la carpeta?, basta con colocarla en la etiqueta "title" o "description" del archivo index.html

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, recien estoy empezando en el mundo del SEO y es normal cometer errores.